# Area calculation of Burnside Curve

Tags: area, plane-curves, beta-function

[Burnside](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BurnsideCurve.html) curve is given by the equation $y^2=x^5-x.$ I intended to find the Area formula in $(2)$ of the the given link. And I found after some mistakes:
$$A=2\int_{-1}^0 \sqrt{x^5-x}dx=2\int_0^1 x^{1/2}(1-x^4)^{1/2}dx\stackrel{x^4=u}{=}\frac12\int_0^1 u^{-5/8}(1-u)^{1/2}du=\frac12B(3/8,3/2)$$
$$=\frac12\frac{\Gamma(3/8)\Gamma(3/2)}{\Gamma(3/8+3/2)}=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{4}\frac{\Gamma(3/8)}{\Gamma(15/8)}.$$

Is there an alternative way of evaluating this integral? Also, how can I find $(3)$ in that link?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The [gamma function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html) obeys the reflection identity
$$\Gamma(z) \Gamma(1 - z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin \pi z}, \tag{42}$$
as well as the recursion
$$\Gamma(z+1) = z \Gamma(z), \tag{39}$$ from which we obtain
$$\Gamma(\tfrac{15}{8}) = \tfrac{7}{8} \Gamma(\tfrac{7}{8}) = \frac{7}{8}\frac{1}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{8})} \cdot \frac{\pi}{\sin \frac{7}{8}\pi}.$$
Hence
$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4} \frac{\Gamma(\frac{3}{8})}{\Gamma(\frac{15}{8})} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4} \cdot \frac{8}{7\pi} \sin \frac{7\pi}{8} \Gamma(\tfrac{1}{8}) \Gamma(\tfrac{3}{8}).$$

Next we evaluate the trigonometric factor by using the identity
$$\sin^2 \theta = \frac{1 - \cos 2\theta}{2},$$ hence
$$\sin^2 \frac{7\pi}{8} = \frac{1 - \cos \frac{7\pi}{4}}{2} = \frac{1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}{2} = \frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{4}.$$  This gives
$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4} \frac{\Gamma(\frac{3}{8})}{\Gamma(\frac{15}{8})} = \frac{2}{7 \sqrt{\pi}} \sqrt{\frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{4}} \Gamma(\tfrac{1}{8})\Gamma(\tfrac{3}{8}) = \frac{1}{7}\sqrt{\frac{2 - \sqrt{2}}{\pi}}  \Gamma(\tfrac{1}{8})\Gamma(\tfrac{3}{8})$$ as claimed.